# recursive combination time-complexity Analysis

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

any explanation for exponential time complexity of the recursive Binomial coefficient in T(n)

```
int C(int n, int k){
  if(n==k || k==0)return 1;
  return C(n-1, k) + C(n-1, k-1);
}
```

Comment: You are summing `1`s generated by the stop clause up to something that is `O(n^min{k,n-k})`, so you need `Omega(n^{k,n-k})` summations.

Answer (score 0):

Let `T(a,b)` be the number of times function `C(a,b)` gets called in the recursive call tree of `C(n,k)`. Since `C(a,b)` gets called from both `C(a+1,b)` and `C(a+1,b+1)` (each time any of these 2 is called) we get `T(a,b)=T(a+1,b)+T(a+1,b+1)`. This is the [Pascal's triangle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle): `T`s in the last level of the recursive call tree form the `n`th level of the Pascal triangle, and thus are exponential with `n` (barring the edge cases eg. `k=1` or `k=n`, so for example `k=n/2`).

You can make your algorithm `O(n*k)` time if you [cache the results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization).